# jQuery cannot call method prior to initialization error on calling ignite ui filtering grid method

Tags: angularjs, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am trying to call a filter method on the infragistics ignite ui grid taking reference from their fiddle example. Seems to behave normally on their fiddle but not on my angularjs app. You may find the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/40xgtcry/

In my angular js app, i am initializing the grid in an angular directive using some dummy data and then i folow that up by calling the igGridFiltering method.

```
define(['directives/directives', 'northwind'],
    function(directives) {
        directives.directive('gridView', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: true,
                link: function (scope) {
                    scope.$on("InventoryDataReady", function  (){
                           // $( '#' + scope.gridSettings.targetId ).igGrid(scope.gridSettings);
                        $('#' + scope.gridSettings.targetId).igGrid({
                            autoGenerateColumns: false,
                            columns: [
                                { headerText: "Employee ID", key: "EmployeeID", dataType: "number" },
                                { headerText: "First Name", key: "FirstName", dataType: "string" },
                                { headerText: "Last Name", key: "LastName", dataType: "string" },
                                { headerText: "Birth Date", key: "BirthDate", dataType: "date" },
                                { headerText: "City", key: "City", dataType: "string" },
                                { headerText: "Postal Code", key: "PostalCode", dataType: "string" }
                            ],
                            dataSource: northwind,
                            responseDataKey: "results",
                            features: [
                                {
                                    name: "Responsive",
                                    enableVerticalRendering: false,
                                    columnSettings: [
                                        {
                                            columnKey: "EmployeeID",
                                            classes: "ui-hidden-phone"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            columnKey: "PostalCode",
                                            classes: "ui-hidden-phone"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Filtering",
                                    type: "local",
                                    mode: "advanced"
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                        $('#' + scope.gridSettings.targetId).igGridFiltering("filter", ([{fieldName: "FirstName", expr: "Nancy", cond: "equals", logic: "OR"}]));

                    });
                }
            };

        });
    });
```

The grid renders just fine but the filter method call produces the following error - 
'Error: cannot call methods on igGridFiltering prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'filter'

Comment: All jquery dependencies are already included. 
jquery-1.4.4.js
jquery.ui.core.js
jquery.ui.widget.js
jquery-tmpl.js 

igGridFiltering API reference - 
http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2012.2/ui.iggridfiltering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem, please note that the infragistics api reference for grid filtering is not accurate. In their sample, they initialize their grid on a div like so -

```
<div id="gridFiltering"></div>
```

However, turns out that for some reason the jquery filtering widget does not initialize unless you hook up the grid to a table.

```
<table id="gridFiltering"></table>
```

They seem to do this for other samples of the igniteui grid but NOT on the api reference for grid filtering.

Answer (score 0):

All the igGrid features are initialized on the table of the igGrid. So there is a difference on whether you initialize the grid on a `div` or a `table`. If the grid is initialized on a `table`, then you can directly call the filtering feature, for example, on the top level element. Otherwise you would need to call it on the table.

```
$('#' + scope.gridSettings.targetId + "_table").igGridFiltering(...);
```